# Onenote MS graph API return only old pages

Tags: onenote, onenote-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

I use OneNote Graph API for personal MS account, and have an issue with GET, I don't get newly created pages, only old updates, more than 10 days ago.

as I understand this problem is not in the Work/School account, but various Graph's procedures don't work there correctly, for example search by tags...so I need to use an exactly personal account,

maybe someone knows how to solve the synchronization/indexing problem between OneNote and the Graph API,
thanks